# Pytorch - RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time while trying to find a sparse feature map

Tags: python, pytorch

I am going to find a sparse feature map for a multi-scale CNN. Because I am new to Pytorch, at first I attempted to implement a code for only one scale. I defined two optimizers, one for filters and one for the feature map. When I run the code, I face the the error. Any suggestion or help by you is greatly appreciated. Below: I brought the code:

The algorithm should work like Expectation Maximization algorithm. First, I fix the kernels, then try to optimize the sparse feature map (*z*) and then kernels (weights) are updated. Of course this is the thing I wanted to follow, I am not sure if it is true in the code. I attached an image file showing the algorithm in case I didn't convey correctly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV05x.jpg)

```
import torch 
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torchvision import datasets

from torchvision import transforms

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print('device is:', device)

# dataset definition
mnist_trainset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
mnist_testset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
mnist_trainset.data = mnist_trainset.data[:10000]
mnist_testset.data = mnist_testset.data[:5000]

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
train_dl = DataLoader(mnist_trainset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
test_dl = DataLoader(mnist_testset, batch_size=1024, shuffle=False)


from torch.optim import SGD 
from torch.nn import Module
from torch.nn import Conv2d
from tqdm import tqdm


from torch.autograd import Variable

import scipy.signal as sps

class MNIST_ISTA(Module):
  
    # define model elements
    def __init__(self):
        self.lambda_ = 0.5e-5
        super(MNIST_ISTA, self).__init__()
      
        self.scale1 = Conv2d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 1, kernel_size=3, bias = False)
        self.z = None        
        self.alpha = 1

    def ista_(self, img_batch):
    
        self.z = torch.normal(0, 1, size = (img_batch.shape[0], img_batch.shape[1], img_batch.shape[2], img_batch.shape[3]), requires_grad=True)  
        converged = False
        optim = SGD([{'params': self.z, "lr": 1e-20 }])
        while not converged:
            
            z_old = self.z.clone().detach()
            
            feature_map = self.scale1(img_batch)
            output_image = sps.fftconvolve(feature_map.detach().numpy(), self.scale1.weight.detach().numpy())
            output_image = torch.from_numpy(output_image)

            loss = ((img_batch-pred)**2).sum() + self.alpha*torch.norm(self.z,p=1)
            loss.backward()
            optim.step()
            
            self.z.grad.zero_()
            self.z.data = self.soft_thresholding_(self.z, self.lambda_ )
            converged = torch.norm(self.z - z_old)/torch.norm(z_old)<1e+8
            
            
            
    def num_flat_features(self, x):
        size = x.size()[1:]
        num = 1
        for s in size:
            num *= s
        return num
            

    def soft_thresholding_(self, x, alpha):
        with torch.no_grad():
            rtn = F.relu(x-alpha)- F.relu(-x-alpha)
        return rtn.data


    def forward(self, img_batch):
      
        self.ista_(img_batch)
        pred = self.scale1(img_batch)
        return pred

    def zero_grad(self):
        self.scale1.zero_grad()   

ista_model = MNIST_ISTA()

optim = SGD([{'params': ista_model.scale1.weight, "lr": 1e-15}])

for epoch in range(5):
    running_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        ista_model.scale1.weight.div_(torch.norm(ista_model.scale1.weight, dim=None, keepdim=True))

    for data in tqdm(train_dl, desc='training', total=len(train_dl)):
        img_batch = data[0]
        pred = ista_model(img_batch)
        loss = ((img_batch - pred) ** 2).sum()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
        ista_model.zero_grad()
```

Comment: I think the problem is that there is no `optim.zero_grad()`, but I'm not sure. Please provide the full text in the standard error.

Comment: Thank you @SalvatoreDanieleBianco for your response. I figured out that apparently using scipy libraries (e.g. fftconvolve) causes the backpropagation  to break. (Correct me if I am wrong). When I remove that, I don't get the error, but now, I am not sure how I can convolve filters with the feature map (4 dimension). I couldn't find any library in Pytorch. Could you help about that?